# Trouble inserting multipolygon into postgres db with postgis extension

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, postgis

I have postgres 10 with the postgis 2.4 extension installed.

```js
db.none(`INSERT INTO resto_poly_sub (foo, bar geom) VALUES $1 $2, 
ST_Force2D(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($3))`, restoPolyArray)
```

Above isn't the full code but I tried to minimize it.

I'm using this to insert my data into the database. It works with points but not MultiPolygons or MultiLineStrings. It will insert all of the data into the db with no errors but when I use a select statement to retrieve the data it comes back with an empty geometry value.

The data that is being inserted, is being pulled from leaflet.

```
[
   {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {
         foo: 17000,
         bar: null
         geom: {
            type: 'MultiPolygon',
            coordinates: [
               [
                  [ -115.35644531250001, 37.4364847574233 ],
                  [ -115.33447265625001, 36.950769770175164 ],
                  [ -114.69726562500001, 37.08673426633463 ],
                  [ -114.70825195312501, 37.27929803862557 ],
                  [ -115.35644531250001, 37.4364847574233 ]
               ]
            ], 
            crs: [Object]
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I am only inserting the properties.

Comment: Thank you guys in advance for the help

Comment: What's the definition of the `resto_point_sub` table? What's the column type for the geometry? What's the error coming from PostGIS? Have you read the [GeoJSON standard](http://geojson.org/)?

Comment: @IvanSanchez There is no error coming from it. It will insert into the table, but the value becomes empty when retrieving it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE resto_poly_sub {
    foo integer NOT NULL,
    bar numeric(10,0),
    geom geometry(MultiPolygon) }

Comment: Try to create the table geometry column without any geometry type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was inserting a polygon into my database rather than a multipolygon so it would cause it to become empty for some reason.

I used this `ST_Force2D(ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geom)))`

Specifically the `ST_Multi()` function to convert it for me.